# How to make Angular UI Grid row editable when button is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using `angular ui grid`.

I have `edit` button showing for each row as last column. I want to change row to `edit` mode when `edit button` clicked.

Appreciated if someone can guide me.

```
{
    field: 'edit',
    displayName: '',
    enableFiltering: false,
    enableSorting: false,
    width: '5%'
},
```

Right now i have made it editable for each cell individually using the following line

```
<div class="grid testGrid" ui-grid="GridOptions" ui-grid-edit ui-grid-row-edit style="width: 100%;"></div>
```

Comment: I can't help you directly, you may have to re-write the ui-grid code to get what you want.  But you can check out this example: [Absolute Grid Knock-Off In AngularJS](http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/absolute-grid-knock-off-angularjs/)

Comment: I don't think, it is easier to achieve that. If you like, you may follow this workaround.http://brianhann.com/create-a-modal-row-editor-for-ui-grid-in-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in ui-grid, as for now, is to avoid using `ui-grid-edit` and implementing some custom templates with `ng-if`s conditions inside.

I built [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0IryRcgLaqyuiiY3luSO?p=preview) as a starting step, there you can see only one button, but you can simply put a similar logic inside your `edit` button.

Comment: It took way to long to find your advice and plunker.  But,disabling ui grid's single-cell-only editing and using ng-if's in the cellTemplate really works to provide whole-line editing.  In my case, I used ng-if="row.isSelected" to determine which div's in my cellTempate would display.